# Problem sending Excel spreadsheet over wcf service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, excel

We have an application set up like this: server - client where the client is built in Silverlight and the server os in plain vb. With the client, you can select an Excel spreadsheet which will need to be processed on the server.

The problem we are experiencing is that in sending the Excel spreadsheet as a stream over Wcf and then saving the stream on the server side causes punctuation to change in formula's (the ";" change to ","). Because of that, we cannot open the excel in our code.

When we manually open the excel, we have no problem and can see the data as it was on the client.

Has anyone experienced this behavior as well?

Comment: Do you mean you're sending an xlsx (or xls) file - an entire file? And what is 'interpunction'?

Comment: Atm, I'm sending the entire file, but i don't have thousands of rows, I think 500 tops and maybe 30-40 columns. I've corrected the "interpunction".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was the version of a third party tool that was bugging us. Getting a newer version solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I've worked with Excel files on a server before I found the easiest way is to save them to disk. It's not ideal but it works.

Comment: that is what i'm trying, but the problem occurs when I'm trying to do this. Somehow the formula punctuation changes to comma seperated instead of ";"-seperated, which causes the formula's to fail.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it could be because of the locale setting on client and server. Are both the systems using the same regional settings? If not you could try using the same locale for both server and client. I am not sure if there is any way to specify the locale to use while streaming dtaa from client to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At them moment, client and server are the samen, as I am building this application on my machine.